# Update highcharts data dynamically on HTML form value change

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I've started to learn coding and trying to create a loan/mortgage calculator as part of my learning. I've tried to go one step further by utilising Highcharts to draw the results but can't get it to work as I want to.

Ideally I want the pie to dynamically update with the new values that are calculated (i.e "Monthly Repayment" and "Monthly Interest Only").

So far I've only been able to get it to re-draw by clicking the "Calculate" button, however it only updates with the correct new values when clicking the button at least twice.

Example: https://codepen.io/sonofauley/pen/rwNLom

```
<body onload="calculate();">

<form method="POST" name="calc" onsubmit="calculate(); return false;">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="loan" value="100000"><br>
    <label>Years</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="years" value="25"><br>
    <label>Rate (%)</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="rate" value="2.50" onkeyup="calculate"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="btn"><br>
    <label>Monthly Repayment</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="monthlyRepayment"><br>
    <label>Monthly Interest Only</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="interest"><br>
    <label>Monthly Capital Repayment</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="capitalRepayment">
    <label>Total Interest</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="totalInterest"><br>
    </form>

    <div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>

    </body>

//the below script is in its own js file "cacl.js"
$(document).on("keyup", calculate());

function calculate() {
  var p = document.querySelector("#loan").value;
  var years = document.querySelector("#years").value;
  var rate = document.querySelector("#rate").value;
  var r = rate / 100 / 12;
  var n = years * 12;
  var m1 = r * Math.pow(1 + r, n);
  var m2 = Math.pow(1 + r, n) - 1;
  var m = (p * (m1 / m2)).toFixed(2);
  var I = ((p - n) / m).toFixed(2);
  var ti = m * n - p;
  var mr = (m - I).toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector("#monthlyRepayment").value = m;
  document.querySelector("#interest").value = I;
  document.querySelector("#totalInterest").value = ti;
  document.querySelector("#capitalRepayment").value = mr;
    }

//the below script is in a separate js file "chart.js"
$(function () {

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var val1,
        val2,
        options;

    val1 = parseFloat($('input[id=monthlyRepayment]').val());
    val2 = parseFloat($('input[id=capitalRepayment]').val());

    options = {
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [val1,val2]
        }]
    };

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was incorrect value calculated which results in incorrect chart formation .Actually you have to call `calculate()` on button click function

replace existing(part) with this

```
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    calculate();
    var val1,
      val2,
      options;

    val1 = parseFloat($('input[id=monthlyRepayment]').val());
    val2 = parseFloat($('input[id=capitalRepayment]').val());

    options = {
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [{name:"Monthly Repayment",y:val1},{name:"Capital Repayment",y:val2}]
      }]
    };

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
  });
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gROWGR) demo